# How to apply IActionFilter only to a single controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I want to handle exceptions for one of my Api controllers in a certain manner.
I've found this sample:

```
public class HttpResponseExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order { get; } = int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException exception)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(exception.Value)
            {
                StatusCode = exception.Status,
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

however then I need to apply this to all controllers. How do I add the filter to a single controller only?

Is inheriting after `ActionFilterAttribute` a correct approach?

```
public class HttpResponseExceptionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```